# I would like to know some Aussie slang terms for well... diarrhoea!

Tags: slang

Only two terms in Strine I had come across for diarrhoea: one is 'A bad case of the trots'. Another is, 'To have an attack of the flying axe handles'. Really! Are these the only two terms in both Aussie and Kiwi slang for the 'runny shits'?

Ta!

Comment: We say "the trots" in BrE too, but any kind of metaphor would be better than your explicit description (and crude tag).

Answer (score 1):

There are various suitably native Australian slang terms identified in *Green's Dictionary of Slang*.

- [**The cocktails**](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/inbb2mi)
- [**Collywobbles**](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/z7jvciq) - *GDoS* attributes this to Standard English *colic* + *wobble*
- [**dry rots**](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/6xibqvq) *GDoS*: rhyming slang with "trots."
- [**flying handicap**](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/kyzf5ma#4w7mkzi)
- [**gullivers**](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/ysxqmwy) - As *GDoS* puts it, "the sufferer ‘travels’ to the lavatory for relief"
- [**tom-tits**](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/dsedx5q) *GDoS*: rhyming slang with "the shits"

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't some new play on "Septic" perhaps related to the current leader.  Maga-way ?  ;)